# How do I add a right button to NavigatorIOS in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Trying to get NavigatorIOS working in React Native but I'm having trouble getting a button to show up on the right. I'm calling this this block of code when the user successfully logs in using Facebook API:

```
this.props.navigator.replace({
      title:"Agni", 
      component: SwipeScreen,
      rightButtonTitle: 'Matches',
      onRightButtonPress: () => { console.log("matches") },
      passProps:{'token': {result: info}},
    });
```

Does calling .replace intead of .push have anything to do with why it won't show up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my `rightButtonTitle` to appear when using `this.props.navigator.push()` as opposed to `this.props.navigator.replace()`.

On the React Native's Github Issues page, [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476) is exactly what you're experiencing. The last comment, from 25 days ago, also states that `replace` suffers from this same issue.